# Summation containing $n$-th roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> If $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}....a_{n-1}$ are the nth roots of unity, then the value of  $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{a_{i}}{3-a_{i}}\right)}.$$

I tried expressing $a_{i}$ in euler form as $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}$ but I am stuck after it.

Edit: It is a question from JEE examination.

Comment: This problem looks quite engaging but I can't read your mathematical expressions.  Try $LaTeX$ !

Comment: Can you use complex integration and residues?

Comment: I am just a class 11 student in India. I dont know all these

Comment: Try using the Taylor series $\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty x^m$ and then $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}=n\,[n\mid m]$ ([Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)). Add your attempt to your question (or write an answer).

Comment: I even dont know these. I have already added my attempt in the question. I could proceed only to one step.

Comment: If you haven't covered these in class, then I am surprised that this question was given. Perhaps this wasn't given in class; in any case, please add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), then we would know what you can use and what you can't. I have written both a complex integration and a series based answer using my hint above, only to be told you can't use those methods.

Comment: Are you familiar with the sums of geometric series? Then you should know that $\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k$. If you know that $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$, from which you can establish $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}=n\,[n\mid m]$.

Comment: I accepted it by mistake. And do post the answer with school mathematic concepts

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity/1909366#1909366 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258846/calculate-product-of-n-th-roots-of-unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}{3-e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\frac13e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}{1-\frac13e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{3^m}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{3^m}n\,[n\mid m]\tag3\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{3^{jn}}n\tag4\\[6pt]
&=\frac{n}{3^n-1}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: cancel $3$ in numerator and denominator
$(2)$: use the Taylor series $\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k$
$(3)$: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}=n\,[n\mid m]$ ([Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket))
$(4)$: select the terms where $m=jn$
$(5)$: sum the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

---

**Explanation of step $\boldsymbol{(3)}$**

Note that the sum of the following finite geometric series
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}=\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi inm}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{2\pi im}{n}}-1}=\frac0{e^{\frac{2\pi im}{n}}-1}\tag6
$$
shows that if $n\nmid m$,
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}=0\tag7
$$
It is pretty simple to see that if $n\mid m$,
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ikm}{n}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}1=n\tag8
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is only a hint,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{a_{i}}{3-a_{i}}\right)}+n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{a_{i}}{3}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(\prod_{j\neq i}{\left(1-\frac{a_{j}}{3}\right)}\right)}}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}{\left(1-\frac{a_{i}}{3}\right)}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then You can use Vieta's formula.

Comment: I dont know what Vietas formula is. Is there anyother way to proceed without using it?

Comment: @dhaneshvijay i have not found solutions without it, but there should be other solutions

Comment: Are you telling about product of roots of an polynomial as Vietas formula?

Comment: @dhaneshvijay yes that one.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use it for numerator alone